# xpath query only child element

Tags: xpath

I am trying to select a array of interaction nodes and then loop though each node and select data from it's child nodes

```
var interactions = xpath.select('//interaction[@aoinclude="true"]', doc);
```

Loop

```
async.each(interactions, parseInteraction, function (err) {
    if(err){
        // A interaction failed
    } else {
        callback(null, 'Fetched quiz data')
    }
});


function parseInteraction(interaction, callback){
    var type = xpath.select('//interaction/@type', interaction);
}
```

My issue is that the parseInteraction fetches nodes from the entire document and not just the current interaction node and outputs an array of all my interactions

xml:

```
<some elements>
    <interactions>
        <interaction>
            <some elements></some nodes>
        </interaction
    </interactions>
    <interactions>
        <interaction>
            <some elements></some nodes>
        </interaction
    </interactions>
    <interactions>
        <interaction>
            <some elements></some nodes>
        </interaction
    </interactions> 
</some nodes>
```

Comment: Your XML doesn't correspond to the XPath expressions being used, i.e no `type` and `aoinclude` attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `interaction` as in `//interaction/@type` supposed to be the child of `interaction` as in `//interaction[@aoinclude="true"]`, then you can simply remove the `descendant-or-self` axis (`//`) from the former :

```
function parseInteraction(interaction, callback){
    var type = xpath.select('interaction/@type', interaction);
}
```

Or use dot (`.`) at the beginning of the XPath to make it relative to current context node :

```
function parseInteraction(interaction, callback){
    var type = xpath.select('./interaction/@type', interaction);
}
```